# Appropriate way to add multiple UIPicker controls on page

Tags: ios, uipickerview

iOS Proficiency: Beginner

If I have a Xib with multiple fields that all need their own Picker View, what's an appropriate/canonical way to add multiple picker views on the page without getting the Design View all cluttered up?

1) Only add the PickerView programmatically and not via the XIB?

2) Use only 1 Picker object and populate it with different values based on the field 
selection?  (Possible memory benefits?)

3) Place the UIPickers on the View with a tiny height/width and then programmatically adjust height when necessary? Not even sure if the height is adjustable.

4)Combination of some of the above?

You can see in the image below, how cluttered it looks already even with just one picker view:
[image]

Comment: In the past I have had a button when pushed it opens up a UIPickerview in an action sheet. Using tags you can determine where the data has to go once selected and what data to show in the UIPickerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only one pickerView will be visible at once, then you should consider using only one pickerView and configure it's delegate/datasource so that you can give it a different datasource for each field.

Unless more than one is visible at once, there really isn't any reason to use more than one in your nib file.  And even if you used more than one, you would still have to configure you delegate/datasource methods to handle each individual picker.

Hope that helps.

EDIT:  It would be a little bit of work, but if you wanted the pickerView to animate in and out of the view whenever you need and if you wanted to clean your Xib up even more you could do the following:

- Create a subview containing your pickerView
- Set up a protocol on the subview to allow you to pass the selected value back to the view controller.
- Set up your viewController to conform to the protocol on your picker subview.
- Set the pickerView to be each textField's inputView.
- Set the textField's delegate methods to configure the dataSource of your subview when editing begins.

By doing this, you have set your textField so that when it receives firstResponder that it will display the pickerView instead of a keyboard.

Comment: This makes sense. My next thought was that I would need to adjust the coordinates of the picker to show up right below each field, but reading logixologist's comment, I realized that the canonical way to show pickers might actually be via Action Sheets

Answer (score 2):

The view that you have with the text fields and picker views would lend itself to be part of a UITableView.

See the calendar app when you add an event.

You can set this up fairly easily by using a static UITableView.

I'm replying on my phone at the moment but will look for a tutorial if you would like.

Comment: Sure, I'd be up for checking out a tutorial if you get a chance. Thanks